# Перевод меню из js на сss

Tags: jquery, css

Как переписать данный код в css

```
$(".sub_top_men3 li>ul").toggle()
$(".sub_top_men3 li").css("position","relative");
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
       el=$(this).find("ul")
       el.toggle().css({
           'position':'absolute',
           'top':'-5px',
           'left':'195px',
           'background':'#65331f',
           'color':'#fff',
           'width':'267px',
           'padding-top':'15px',
           'padding-bottom':'20px'
       });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
       el.hide();
    }},
'.sub_top_men3 li');
```

Написал вот так, но оно не работает

```
<style>
.sub_top_men3>ul>li{
    display: none;
}

.sub_top_men3 li {
    position: relative;
}

.sub_top_men3>ul>li:hover {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-5px;
    left:195px;
    background:#65331f;
    color:#fff;
    width:267px;
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Саму разметку меню добавьте, а то не понятно к чему применять.

Comment: А зачем ты css hover вешаешь на li элемент, когда в js коде оно вешается на ul  в целом ? надо просто .sub_top_men3>ul:hover